# Running Python script, 'Memory error', 'for' loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to model the three-body problem, where I have three generalized coordinates (one radial and two angular) and three second order (coupled) differential equations. I want to see how the system evolves while changing the initial conditions, rho[0].
Is there anything wrong in my script? The variables and parameters are well defined above, so I will omit them; here's the code:

```
    for i in range(1000000,10000000,1000000):
        rho[0] = i

        rho[1] = rho[0] + vrho*dt
        theta[1] = theta[0] + vtheta*dt #angulos radianes
        phi[1] = phi[0] + vphi*dt

        for t in range(1, N-1):
        #Velocidades de las coordenadas
            v[0,t-1] = (rho[t] - rho[t-1])/dt
            v[1,t-1] = (theta[t] - theta[t-1])/dt
            v[2,t-1] = (phi[t] - phi[t-1])/dt

        #"Ecuaciones diferenciales"
            rho[t+1] = (2*rho[t] - rho[t-1]) + (rho[t]*(v[2,t-1]**2) - G*M/(rho[t]**2) - (9*G*M*((np.cos(theta[t]-phi[t]))**2)*(l**2))/(8*(rho[t]**4)))*(dt**2)
            theta[t+1] = (2*theta[t] - theta[t-1]) + ((-3*G*M*np.sin(2*(theta[t]-phi[t])))/(2*(rho[t]**3)))*(dt**2)
            phi[t+1] = (2*phi[t] - phi[t-1]) + ((3*G*M*np.sin(2*(theta[t]-phi[t]))*(l**2))/(8*(rho[t]**5)) - (2*v[0,t-1]*v[2,t-1])/(rho[t]))*(dt**2)

            for j in range(0,N):
                x[j] = rho[j]*np.cos(phi[j])
                y[j] = rho[j]*np.sin(phi[j])

                plt.plot(x,y)
```

And this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4c789e1dfc65> in <module>()
     21             y[j] = rho[j]*np.sin(phi[j])
     22 
---> 23             plt.plot(x,y)
```

What I tried to do was to make python solve the ODE's for different initial conditions, saving rho, theta, phi and the V vector in orden to manipulate them. Given the fact that I want the trajectory of the body, for those values of rho and phi, I want to turn them to cartesian, plot the trajectory, and then restart the ODE's with the next initial condition for rho.

I had to introduce the j counter since x and y were defined as np.zeros(N) in order to match the dimensions of rho, theta and phi. The counter represents the position of such vector, and the idea is that for each position in rho and phi, the cartesian equivalent is saved in the same position. Since t goes up to N-1, and therefore the last t available is N-2, I didn't know how to avoid adding another for; in order to solve the starting point difference, I could write the last 'for' switching j for t-1, but wouldn't that cause a dimensional error?

Comment: You have a double-nested loop to N, so your arrays will be O(N^2) in size.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way to transform polar to cartesian coordinates for each value of t? I already tried  'pol2cart' but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you going to tell me what N is?

Comment: Is it intentional that plt.plot is *inside* the `for j in ...` loop? Don't you want to finish computing x and y before plotting them?

Comment: Sorry, N is the dimension of a vector and is set to 100000, while T=300 and dt=T/N.
But I've tried running the code with other values

Comment: I think I'm wrong about the double-nested loop memory use - the lists are all 1-D. You might still be able to save memory tho by not storing the complete history of time after you've plotted it - so `v`, `rho`, `theta` and `phi` keep a lot of history but look like you only ever need [t] and [t-1] at any given step.

Comment: @NickWhite Doesn't it plot the last value of (x,y) if I write it outside the loop?? I want every value of N represented in a graph

Comment: The j loop looks odd - should that whole thing be dedented to only plot j after the full rho, phi etc lists have been populated?

Comment: @ffalk you said that N is 100000, what do you mean by 'I want every value of N represented in a graph'? Do you mean every value of t (which has a range 0-N) and I'm assuming represents time? Edit: Or even "for every value of i"?

Comment: What I tried to do was to make python solve the ODE's for different initial conditions, saving rho, theta, phi and the V vector in orden to manipulate them. Given the fact that I want the trajectory of the body, for those values of rho and phi, I want to turn them to cartesian, plot the trajectory, and then restart the ODE's with the next initial condition for rho

Comment: @ffalk I'm not familiar with pyplot, but if x and y are arrays that you're passing in, you should only have to pass them in once. Alternatively, do you mean to call `plt.plot(x[j], y[j])` for each j in that inner loop?

Comment: Do you want one plot (line) for each value of `i`, or one plot for each value of `t`, for each value of `i`?

Comment: @NickWhite, I had to introduce the j counter since x and y were defined as np.zeros(N) in order to match the dimensions of rho, theta and phi. The counter represents the position of such vector, and the idea is that for each position in rho and  phi, the cartesian equivalent is saved in the same position. Since t goes up to N-1, and therefore the last t available is N-2, I didn't know how to avoid adding another for; in order to solve the starting point difference, I could write the last 'for' switching j for t-1, but wouldn't that cause a dimensional error?

Comment: @TomDalton for each value of 'i' I want to plot the trajectory of the body from start to finish, that is, for all the values of 't' which represents time

Comment: Yes, but the core problem is that you're calling the plot function repeatedly with the entire data set. See @TomDalton 's answer below; I think fixing the indentation as he suggests will do it.

Comment: Yep - see my answer below, I think it was just the plotting part was badly indented/nested.

Comment: Also thanks to Nick for getting me off the wrong track I started on, he probably deserves credit for the answer below.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! While it definitely improved the results, the program only returned one plot, not the ten or so it was supposed to given the step of i. Should I indent the line 'plt.plot(x,y)' so that it is inside the j loop?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following code:

```
for i in range(1000000,10000000,1000000):
    rho[0] = i

    rho[1] = rho[0] + vrho*dt
    theta[1] = theta[0] + vtheta*dt #angulos radianes
    phi[1] = phi[0] + vphi*dt

    for t in range(1, N-1):
        # Velocidades de las coordenadas
        v[0,t-1] = (rho[t] - rho[t-1])/dt
        v[1,t-1] = (theta[t] - theta[t-1])/dt
        v[2,t-1] = (phi[t] - phi[t-1])/dt

        # "Ecuaciones diferenciales"
        rho[t+1] = (2*rho[t] - rho[t-1]) + (rho[t]*(v[2,t-1]**2) - G*M/(rho[t]**2) - (9*G*M*((np.cos(theta[t]-phi[t]))**2)*(l**2))/(8*(rho[t]**4)))*(dt**2)
        theta[t+1] = (2*theta[t] - theta[t-1]) + ((-3*G*M*np.sin(2*(theta[t]-phi[t])))/(2*(rho[t]**3)))*(dt**2)
        phi[t+1] = (2*phi[t] - phi[t-1]) + ((3*G*M*np.sin(2*(theta[t]-phi[t]))*(l**2))/(8*(rho[t]**5)) - (2*v[0,t-1]*v[2,t-1])/(rho[t]))*(dt**2)

    for j in range(0,N):
        x[j] = rho[j]*np.cos(phi[j])
        y[j] = rho[j]*np.sin(phi[j])

    plt.plot(x,y)
```

I think there was some bad indentation at the plotting stage, meaning every time you wanted to plot a single line, you were actually plotting N ^ 2 lines!

Comment: I just ran the code using spyder, and while it returned no error, it only plotted one of the odes' solutions. (I've been examining the behaviour manually with various initial conditions, but tried to work out a way to optimize the code in order to make it evaluate different set of IC's for rho[0], and then, depending on those results, vary the range and step of i)

Comment: It might be worth printing out the first few pairs for x and y, for each i. You might see the values are crazy, or that it's not making it to the second iteration of the i loop, or something else.